# Open Details section in docs made with Workbench

Tags: packages, documentation, workbench

I'm making some package docs with Workbench (10.1.822).  The "Details" section is closed by default, which is a shame because I've got some useful info there that would be easy to overlook:
[image]

Is there some way I could hack up the doc-building process in Workbench to make these open by default?